# Publishing Google Sheet to web as GeoJSON file?

Tags: geojson, mapbox, google

I am trying to create a map in Mapbox to be embedded on a website and have the embedded map automatically update every time the source data is updated. I have my source data in a Google sheet and have discovered how to manually convert that into a GeoJSON file and then manually import that file into Mapbox, so that the data populates my map. However, I would like to find a way to automate this process. My proposed solution is that I publish the sheet to the web as a GeoJSON file and then set it to automatically republish whenever changes are made. However, I don't see an option for publishing a sheet as a geoJSON file.

Does anyone know of a script for this?

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox publishes something called **Geo For Google Docs**:
https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs/

It's another google drive script-based solution.

From the repo:

> Geo for Google Docs is a set of tools that make it easy to use data from Google Docs Spreadsheets in TileMill, an open source map design studio.
>
> Uses
>
> - Export spreadsheet data to GeoJSON Any spreadsheet with geocodes (longitude and latitude coordinates) can be exported to a TileMill-ready file.

It's not entirely automated, meaning you still have to manually download the geojson file (as far as I know you can't use `curl` or `wget` directly). But it does at least save a step of converting after downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of Python library suggestions you could use to do the task:

1. Get the data from the Google Spreadsheet

   [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread]) should help you getting the data from the spreadsheet
2. Generate a GeoJSON

   [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/index.html) will help you to generate the GeoJSON
3. Publish the GeoJSON on the web

   [geojsonio.py](https://github.com/jwass/geojsonio.py) will help you to push the GeoJSON to geojson.io

If you combine them nicely you should be able to do your task.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Sheetsee.js](http://jlord.us/sheetsee.js/). It is a client-side library for connecting Google Spreadsheets to a website and visualizing the information in tables, maps and charts. It has a **createGeoJSON** function for creating geojson from your Google Spreadsheet data. You can also use one of its components, [sheetsee-maps](https://github.com/jlord/sheetsee-maps), which is built on Mapbox.js.

Using Sheetsee would look something like this:

1. Link to Sheetsee.js, tabletop.js and jQuery in your HTML head.
2. Create a placeholder  in your HTML for the map you want to have.
3. Create templates for tables in  tags. This is for the info you want to see in the popups.
4. Inside of a  tag initialize Tabletop.js. It waits for the document to load and then initializes tabletop and calls back a function when it has returned with the spreadsheet data.

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gData
    var URL = "YOURSPREADSHEETSKEYHERE"
    Tabletop.init( { key: URL, callback: callback, simpleSheet: true } )
   })
5. Define the function that Tabletop.js calls when it returns with the data. This function will contain all the Sheetsee.js functions that you use for the maps, charts and tables you desire. Style it up with some CSS.

   function callback(data) {
    // All the sheetsee things you want to do!
   }

You can then just set it and forget it. Now all you need to do is edit the spreadsheet and visitors will get the latest information every time they load the page. Here are some [demos](http://jlord.us/sheetsee.js/demos/demo-map.html) and the [documentation](http://jlord.us/sheetsee.js/docs/sheetsee-maps.html).

I hope that solves your problem. Good luck!

Disclaimer: I am not the author of the project. I just found it and think it's cool :)

Comment: That's a really promising library.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you first modify [this](http://pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2013/10/sheetasjson-google-spreadsheet-data-as-json/) Google Apps Script to create a URL that parses your Google Sheets into JSON.  Then use Mapbox to [load](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geojson-marker-from-url/) the GeoJSON from the URL you created.

This is an interesting application and I hope you share with the community if you get it working.

Comment: I've used a similar solution for json in the past and it works great; the problem  is that it won't register the x, y columns (e.g. lon/lat) as geometry, i.e. this will publish json not geojson

Comment: What won't register the X,Y columns, Mapbox?